# ASP.NET Core Web App - all endpoints return 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am working on an ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017, set to run in IIS Express. The project was started by other colleagues, and I just cloned the repo, but on my machine, all API endpoints return 404 Not Found. 
I've tried removing all configurations from Startup class, keeping only the Mvc functionality, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So apparently I had to delete all the temporary folders that VS or other editors generate. Once I deleted `.vs`, `.vscode` folders, and restarted Visual Studio, everything was working again. Somehow, the config files that VS generates were routing the API requests to `'/api/api/[controller]'`, instead of just `'/api/[controller]'`.

Comment: and this is the reason why `.vs` and `.vscode` are usually added to `.gitignore` file.

Comment: they are not commited to the source control. My own instance of Visual Studio broke the launch.

Comment: same problem with latest Visual Studio 2019, asp.net core 2.1. My .vs folder was not checked into source control. Deleting the folder corrected the problem, thank you so much.

Comment: I just got this problem for the first time with a .NET Core 3.1 Web API project. I must have edited the App URL in Properties of the Web API project because the applicationhost.config in `.vs` had a second `<application>` pointing to the same physical path to the project with `path="/api"`. I actually got a hint about this problem and ignored it- I was getting ANCM In-Process Start Error indicating two apps running in the same app pool set to run `InProcess` instead of `OutOfProcess`. You shouldn't have to set it to `OutOfProcess` for IIS Express though, ergo issue with applicationhost.config.